# Crash log from console log

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash, crash-reports

I have face the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when running my osx application, I can't find what problem it occurs. Can anybody help me to resolve this error
Im using OSX 10.9.3, XCode 5.1

```
Crashed Thread:  5  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
 
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT
 
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: isEqual:
 
 
Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff97bba005 vsnprintf + 57
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff97be7b56 __snprintf_chk + 128
2   libsystem_asl.dylib           0x00007fff8c9fe776 asl_string_append_char_no_encoding + 143
3   libsystem_asl.dylib           0x00007fff8ca044bc asl_msg_to_string_raw + 236
4   libsystem_asl.dylib           0x00007fff8c9fc3bb _asl_send_message + 1637
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91cadfbd __CFLogCString + 861
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91cadc27 _CFLogvEx + 263
7   com.apple.Foundation          0x00007fff90833d0c NSLogv + 79
8   com.apple.Foundation          0x00007fff90833c98 NSLog + 148
9   com.myapp.client      0x00000001079153d6 0x10790b000 + 41942
10  com.myapp.client      0x0000000107910744 0x10790b000 + 22340
11  com.myapp.client      0x0000000107932d08 0x10790b000 + 163080
12  com.myapp.client      0x000000010793281d 0x10790b000 + 161821
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91ccac81 _signalEventSync + 385
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91ccaac8 _cfstream_solo_signalEventSync + 328
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91cca93f _CFStreamSignalEvent + 623
16  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff8c86afba CoreReadStreamCFStreamSupport::coreStreamReadEvent(__CoreReadStream*, unsigned long) + 102
17  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff8c86af29 CoreReadStreamClient::coreStreamEventsAvailable(unsigned long) + 53
18  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff8c96cfa5 CoreStreamBase::_callClientNow(CoreStreamClient*) + 53
19  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff8c86ac49 CoreStreamBase::_streamSetEventAndScheduleDelivery(unsigned long, unsigned char) + 183
20  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff8c86a9d2 SocketStream::dispatchSignalFromSocketCallbackUnlocked(SocketStreamSignalHolder *) + 74
21  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff8c86a100 SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 206
22  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff8c86a002 SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 64
23  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91cca107 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 855
24  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c8a661 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7bd12 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7b49f __CFRunLoopRun + 831
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7af25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
28  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff92435a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
29  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff924357b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
30  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff924355bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
31  com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff8e31b26e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
32  com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff8e31a8bb -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
33  com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff8e30e9bc -[NSApplication run] + 553
34  com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff8e2f97a3 NSApplicationMain + 940
35  libdyld.dylib                 0x00007fff968465fd start + 1
 
Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff979f8662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff93493421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff93493136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52
 
Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff979f3a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff979f2d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7bfc5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7b5e9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7af25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation          0x00007fff90856967 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation          0x00007fff9085676b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f0899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f072a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f4fc9 thread_start + 13
 
Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff979f79aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91cc7ab3 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f0899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f072a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f4fc9 thread_start + 13
 
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff979f3a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff979f2d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7bfc5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7b5e9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff91c7af25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff8e4bb05e _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f0899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f072a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f4fc9 thread_start + 13
 
Thread 5 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libobjc.A.dylib               0x00007fff92767097 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff8e3415ea -[NSButtonCell setImage:] + 82
2   com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff8e61a59d -[NSStatusItem setImage:] + 50
3   com.myapp.client      0x000000010791543d 0x10790b000 + 42045
4   com.myapp.client      0x0000000107932db0 0x10790b000 + 163248
5   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff934941bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff9349128d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff93493082 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
8   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff93494177 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f1ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8e2f4fb9 start_wqthread + 13
 
Thread 5 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000060800027a080  rbx: 0x0000610000138920  rcx: 0x000000000a444000  rdx: 0x00006200002623c0
  rdi: 0x000060800027a080  rsi: 0x00007fff8ed47fdc  rbp: 0x0000000107afec80  rsp: 0x0000000107afec58
   r8: 0x000000000000007f   r9: 0xffff9dffffd9dc3f  r10: 0x00007fff8ed47fdc  r11: 0xbadd0039a02ebead
  r12: 0x000060800009d5b0  r13: 0x0000000000000001  r14: 0x00006200002623c0  r15: 0x0000000000000060
  rip: 0x00007fff92767097  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000107a2d000
 
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     13
```

Comment: Yeah you have to symbolicate it before it's any use.

Comment: I don't know about what is symbolicate. can tell what is it. @trojanfoe

Comment: Apple can tell you better than I can.

Comment: I'm not yet deliver in mac store. I release it to my testing team. it works fine in my mac. but in testing team mac pc got this error. @trojanfoe

Comment: @trojanfoe not do symbolicate my app.

Comment: So are you giving your testers the app that you've *Archived*?  If so you have the exact version of the app the crash occurred on (you'll need to use proper versioning in order to know this).

Comment: @trojanfoe I have release it with proper versions. But till now i not change build version. It still "1". I change only version number in Targets. Ok lets check again. Can you clear onething. is this above issue mentioned anything wrong code or wrongly implemented in my app as based on crash?

Comment: Yes.  The crash originated in your code and was caused by a call to `[NSStatusItem setImage:]`.  The thing about using *Archive* to create the test apps is that you have a saved version of the app and the debug symbols, which allows symbolication.  If you didn't use *Archive* then I would imagine you are screwed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64476/discussion-between-akk-and-trojanfoe).

Comment: I have put this code. is this right? 
NSImage *statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Warning.png"];
        [myStatusItem setImage:statusImage];   The image set as based on service received values. @trojanfoe

Answer (score 0):

How about change the Xcode Run setting to "release" instead "Debug" in Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme..

and also enable zombie objects

Comment: What about handling crash reports from customer devices sent via Apple?  Your answer won't help then.

Comment: In my opinion, it may make this issue can be reproducible in xcode if change debug to release..

Comment: I cant get this error in my developing mac. It happends recently in Testing team mac. I was release it using "debug" mode. Till now, the app working fine in my mac. @trojanfoe , gogoqaz